# How to create multiple check boxes in for loop in Java?

Tags: java, swing, jcheckbox

I am writing a Java program in which I have to create multiple check boxes in for loop like this:

```
123 409 123 []
234 587 344 []
342 534 343 []
```

I have to use only those values in a row which is checked. Can you help me how to create multiple check boxes than how use selected values from that row?

Suppose first row is selected than i want all three values.

I have to create at least 30 checkboxs in one loop and there are four loops. I have no idea how to implement it.

Comment: What presentation technology are you using (Swing, JSF, ...)?

Answer (score 1):

I implemented a little raw example that should help you to get your result. I suggest you to try this and if it satisfies your needs, I will be glad to give you more details and edit my answer. Keep in mind that if you need to have only **one** row selected, you should prefer `JRadioButton`.

```
package stackoverflow.answers;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class SwingCheckBoxDemo extends JPanel implements ItemListener {

    private HashMap<JCheckBox, ArrayList<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
    private JLabel _label;

    private static final int MAX_CHECKS = 30;

    public SwingCheckBoxDemo() {
        super(new BorderLayout());

        JCheckBox checkBox;
        Random r = new Random();

        JPanel checkPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        _label = new JLabel("You selected nothing");
        checkPanel.add(_label);

        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_CHECKS; i++) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                Integer temp = (r.nextInt()) % 100;
                a.add(temp);
                sb.append(temp).append(" ");
            }

            checkBox = new JCheckBox(sb.toString().trim());
            checkBox.setName("CheckBox" + i);
            checkBox.addItemListener(this);
            map.put(checkBox, a);
            checkPanel.add(checkBox);
        }

        add(checkPanel);

    }

    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {

        JCheckBox source = (JCheckBox) e.getItemSelectable();

        if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {

            ArrayList<Integer> list = map.get(source);

            _label.setText("You've just selected " + list);

        }

    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {

        JFrame _frame = new JFrame("Check box loop");
        _frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        _frame.setSize(800, 600);

        JComponent newContentPane = new SwingCheckBoxDemo();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true);
        _frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

        _frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```